# Is writing a compiler Hello World for F#?

Tags: f#

I don't believe seeing [this](http://www.communityforfsharp.net/april-2010-live-meeting-detail). It says:

> For April, Chris Smith will be presenting on writing a Java to x86 Compiler in F#.

The presentation may go on for an hour or two which definitely is not enough to write a *compiler*. I've heard that F# is powerful, but *this* powerful?

Well, all I wanted to ask is this: Can you write a compiler in F# that quickly?

Comment: Wait until you see Haskell :-)

Comment: In his defense, he may be from a country that doesn't celebrate April Fool's Day

Comment: "This talk will go over the FSMiniJava project, a compiler converting a subset of the Java language into x86 assembler and then producing working executables - all written in F#! The talk will cover Lex and Yacc, abstract syntax trees, and op-code generation." - from what you pointed to. That is an entirely reasonable topic for a two hour presentation. It does not say anything about coding live on stage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about an actual programming problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Giving a presentation about a project isn't the same thing as implementing the whole project during the presentation.

It's perfectly possible to present some interesting aspects of a Java to x86 compiler within an hour, and even show some code: but that's not the same as creating all the code then and there.

Comment: You should have seen Bill Gates' presentation on Windows Vista. He seemed pretty winded after talking about/implementing the new windowing system.

Answer (score 19):

Let's first start with a few corrections:

- It's not a Java compiler, it's a compiler for a small *subset* of Java.
- It doesn't say anywhere that the compiler will be *written* in the time, only that it will be *explained*.
- In fact, it doesn't even say that, it says, it will be *presented*. Heck, I can present GCC in 3 minutes. It's not gonna be a very *useful* presentation, but it's gonna be a presentation.

That said, explaining a well-structured, simple compiler for a simple language implemented in a language which is well-suited for writing compilers within an hour is definitely feasible.

F# is a member of the ML family of languages (specifically, a close cousin of OCaml), and those are indeed well-suited for writing compilers. In fact, the *reason* why Robin Milner chose the name ML (meta language) for his language, was because it is *specifically designed* for writing compilers. A compiler is basically a big function (thus making it very natural to implement in a functional language) that detects patterns (thus making it very natural to implement in a language with pattern matching) and executes a little bit of code for each pattern it detects (thus making it very natural to implement in a language with first-class functions). And whaddayaknow? F# is a functional language with very sophisticated pattern matching facilities. Another nice feature is an expressive type system with algebraic data types and discriminated unions which makes it very easy to represent Abstract Syntax Trees.

At the Lang.NET Symposium Jason Olson gave [a talk on F#](http://LangNETSymposium.Com/2009/talks/24-JasonOlson-FSharp.html), during which he showed some pieces of an interpreter that he is currently working on that demonstrate these features very well.

Fredrik Holmström is currently working on [IronJS](http://IronJS.Com/), an ECMAScript 3 implementation for the Dynamic Language Runtime. Take a look at the [code](https://GitHub.Com/FHolm/IronJS/), specifically the [AST types](https://GitHub.Com/FHolm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/IronJS/Ast.Types.fs) and some of the [analysis](https://GitHub.Com/FHolm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/IronJS/Ast.Analyzer.fs) and [parsing](https://GitHub.Com/FHolm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/IronJS/Ast.fs) code.

[Jonathan Tang's Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://Jonathan.Tang.Name/files/scheme_in_48/tutorial/overview.html) is another good example of writing an interpreter, this time in Haskell which shares many features with F#.

[The 90 Minute Scheme to C compiler by Marc Feeley](http://WWW.IRO.UMontreal.Ca/%7Eboucherd/mslug/meetings/20041020/minutes-en) is a presentation about a Scheme compiler written in Scheme.

In [Implementing Scheme in Ruby](http://SkillsMatter.Com/podcast/ajax-ria/implementing-scheme-in-ruby/), James Coglan teaches the audience Scheme, live-codes and explains a Scheme interpreter in Ruby and writes a couple of sample Scheme programs, all in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

Java is a fairly complex language, so I suppose that Chris isn't going to implement a complete Java compiler. However, his talk really points out that manipulating with code (and tree-like structures in general) is *much* easier in F# than in any other .NET language. That's why F# has been used in various static analysis tools (e.g. Microsoft's static driver verifier)

Tools like fslex and fsyacc make it easy to write parser for a language. Chris has a [blog with simple mathematical expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/01/18/fslex-Sample.aspx). Robert Pickering wrote [a more sophisticated example](http://strangelights.com/blog/archive/2006/05/11/1302.aspx) that actually generates IL code (compiles mathematical expressions to .NET) in just a few lines of code. This can be even easier on .NET 4.0 if you generate code using Expression Trees.

So I suppose that even if he was writing the compiler from scratch, he could write compiler for a langauge that can be used to write non-trivial sample programs.

Comment: +1 but note that emitting CIL directly tends to generate *much* faster code than using expression trees.

Answer (score 5):

> Can you write a compiler in F# that quickly?

I have written two tiny compilers in F# over the past week, each in about that much time. So yes, it can be done. [Here](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-llvm-from-f-under-windows.html) is one of them.

Note that the ML family of languages that F# is descended from were specifically designed for this application (metaprogramming).